# How do I override the default visibility for a specific setter template in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, code-generation

I'm using Intellij 2016.1.3 and would like to create a setter template that does not have a public visibility.  I do not want the change the default visibility for all templates.  Is this possible?